# medskipamount, default value in article class

Tags: spacing, lengths

What is the default value of `medskipamount` in the `article` class? I have not been able to locate this information. Is there some database where default values of various parameters can be accessed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `\showthe\medskipamount` will produce the answer:

> 6.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt.

`\medskipamount` is a "rubber length", i.e., it can be stretched (`plus`) or shrunk (`minus`) by a certain amount. (This is useful for, e.g., stretching page contents so that the last text line will be positioned exactly at the bottom margin.)

`\medskipamount` is not defined by `article.cls`, but part of the LaTeX kernel; its definition  can be found in section 16.5 *"Vertical spacing"* of [source2e](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/doc/source2e.pdf).

Comment: Perfect, thanks lockstep. What does the plus/minus mean? In some environments the medskipamount value will differ by that amount?

Comment: @user001: Yes. Please [read some documentation on TeX](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?introduction=yes). The concept you are looking for is _glue_.

Comment: @lockstep May I ask that what is `\medskipamount` use for? Is there something that LaTeX uses this length to typeset? I've tried to set `\medskipamount=50pt` to see what is going to change, but nothing changed.

Comment: @Eric It is used in the `\medskip` macro which is defined as `\vskip\medskipamount`.

Comment: @lockstep Thanks, so general speaking, only when the author intentionally and explicitly use the command `\medskip` to add a vertical space whose size is specified by `\medskipamount`, this length is used. By default, LaTeX doesn't use this length right? In other words, if I find there is some vertical space typeset by the LaTeX in my document weird and I didn't use any `\medskip`, then I should know that it has nothing to do with `\medskip` or `\medskipamount.`

Answer (score 4):

Using `\showthe\medskipamount` will print the quantity in your `.log` file, just like `\show\medskip` will print

```
> \medskip=macro:
->\vspace \medskipamount .
```

in your `.log` file, showing what the macro does. For shorthand (rather than viewing the `.log` file), you can also print the amount in your actual document output using `\the\medskipamount`.

The [`printlen` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/printlen) is made especially for printing lengths using `\printlength{<len>}` within your document and switching between measurement units when printing via `\uselengthunit{<unit>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{printlen}% http://ctan.org/pkg/printlen
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \verb!\parskip! in points (\verb!pt!): & \the\parskip \\
  \verb!\textwidth! in inches (\verb!in!): & \uselengthunit{in}\printlength{\textwidth} \\
  \verb!3cm! in points (\verb!pt!): & \uselengthunit{pt}\printlength{\dimexpr3cm} \\
  \verb!2pt+.5\parindent-3bp! in centimetres (\verb!cm!): & \uselengthunit{cm}\printlength{\dimexpr2pt+.5\parindent-3bp}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Printing of font-specific components can vary depending on where it's used within the document. For example, `\baselineskip` is `0pt` within `tabular`, but `12pt` within regular text (when using `\documentclass{article}`).